# Clean up while performing very large number of floating point operations

Tags: scala

I have an algorithm that performs a huge number of operations. It results in a

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Since there is nothing I can do to reuse the doubles involved in previous operations, no matter how much memory is allocated to the JVM it will eventually fill up. How can I avoid this problem? GC configuration? Some other JVM options?

EDIT: some relevant code.

So, here is what Im trying to execute -

```
def calculateModel(d: Array[structure.Vector], y: structure.Vector): Model = {
    val H = new Matrix(d)
    val w = H.transpose.multiply(H).inverse.multiply(H.transpose).multiply(y)
    return new Model(w, null, null)
}
```

Vector and Matrix are classes that hold Array[Double] and have respective operations for vectors and matrices.

Since I called this method from a main() method in the IDE, I think what happened is none of the objects that would be local scope in main() made it to the heap. A better explanation is very welcome :)

Comment: `it will eventually fill up` ... only if there are variables which cannot be garbage collected because they are still being referenced.  Can you include some sample code?

Comment: I would imagine then it would result in OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space... I dont think code will make much sense but Ill post some later tonght.

Comment: Primitives don't go on the heap AFAIK, but maybe I'm wrong.